# Show UIAlertView if UITableView is empty

Tags: iphone, xcode, count, tableview

I have RSS, and the UITableView loads data from it, how can I show UIAlertView if the UITableView is empty, but not by count of an array because the array is different every time it is refreshed, is there some kind of function which will check if UITableView is empty after it completes drawing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the `UITableView` itself. So assuming you have a single section you could do the following ...

```
// Reload the tableview
[tableView reloadData];
// Test the number of rows in the first section
if ([tableView numberofRowsInSection:0] == 0) {
    // Display UIAlertView here
}
```

EDIT; Based on the comments below ...

In your header file (.h) iVar declarations ...

```
int feedCount;
int feedsParsed;
```

In your implementation ...

```
- (void)refresh {
    feedCount = 0;
    feedsParsed = 0;

    [feedParser stopParsing];
    self.title = @"Refreshing...";
    [parsedItems removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *imePredmeta in [Data variables].mojiPredmeti) {
        ... // I've removed these lines for brevity but they are still required
        [feedParser parse];
        feedCount += 1;
    }
    // Delete everything else after this line
}

- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
    feedsParsed += 1;
    if (feedsParsed == feedCount) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        if ([self.tableView numberofRowsInSection:0] == 0) {
            // Fade out tableview and display alert here as we now know for
            // sure that there are no more feeds to parse and we definitely
            // have nothing to display
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: it says the method numberofRowsInSection is not found

Comment: One more question, it works, but sometimes the notification loads before drawing is done and it shows it when it shouldn't, how to solve this?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you're reloading the data before the RSS has finished loading. `reloadData` is synchronous as it's called on the main thread meaning the `if` condition won't get called until it's completed reloading. Without seeing your code I cannot say anymore I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the MWFeedParser delegate method `- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser` otherwise you are trying to reload the data before parsing has finished. You will also need to keep track of the number of feeds vs the number successfully parsed feeds since you are parsing several feeds at once, the above delegate method will be called more than once.

Comment: Tried it now, still the same problem, because the (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser is called multiple times, it depends how many objects are in the array

Comment: Should I use NSOperationQueue?

Comment: No, you should be able to work with what you already have. What class is `[Data variables].mojiPredmeti` ?

Comment: So then you can query it's `count` property to determine how many feeds are to be parsed. Therefore, what I'd do is have an iVar declared in the header called something like `feedCount`. Set it to zero at the top of your `refresh` method and then increment it by one in `feedParserDidFinish` each time that method is called. Compare `feedCount` to the count of the mutable array and once they match call `reloadData' on your tableview.

Comment: Check this out:
http://pastebin.com/vn4s5bDv

It shows the alert before the parsing is finished, why?

Comment: Yes, I tried that to half an hour ago, and again, the uilaertview is showed before parsing is done

Comment: I'd need to see all your code, so I can match up the `NSLog` calls

Comment: The problem is you are still calling `reloadData` from in the same method as setting up the feed parsing which will never work because you **must** wait until **all** parsing has finished before reloading the tableview. That's why I suggest it be called from inside the delegate method, but only after making sure all feeds have been parsed which can be done using an independent counter as outlined above. Each time you create a feed a corresponding call with eventually be made to the delegate method; only reload the tableview when you are sure the final call has been received.

Comment: ok, I've deleted the [self.tableView reloadData]; from (void)refresh, but it still shows the uialert before parsing is finished

2011-09-06 15:01:36.403 TVZ Info[1483:b303] Begin refresh
2011-09-06 15:01:36.409 TVZ Info[1483:b303] SHOWING ALERT!
etc...

So, what should I write in code to wait until all parsing is finished, and then check if the table is empty?

I guess it begins parsing and in the same time, before the parsing is finished, it runs the if statement to check if the table is empty, if that's even possible

Comment: Hmm will try to work something out and let you know, if you have more ideas please let me know, I am having troubles with this 3 days, and thanks man for all your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I've updated my original answer with how I would approach it; let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I've solved it with counter, and I've put in didFinishFeeding code to check if the feedCounter matches the count of objects in mojiPredmeti and if it does it reloads and checks if the table is empty :)

I've go one more question, how to show info.title in front of item.title, I want to have RSS channel title in front of every item.title

Comment: Why not use sections and have each section represent a different channel. This would probably look a lot cleaner too.

Comment: I want to sort all rss items by date, so I want that in the title of every item is channel name, but don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop round the array and check to determine if there are no results.
Please post your existing tableview code if you want a more explicit answer.

edit: micpringle answer above is better.